# Colloboration between T-SQL Table and Excel Sheet(s)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, excel

Let's say I have a T-SQL table with 20-30 columns and 2-3 millions rows (huge table). I want to allow a user to update this data directly (the solution must work for different tables). I generally have the following options:

- to create simple web interface displaying only part of the data via paging
- to create desktop application which can download the data (on parts) and sync it when it is changed

This will probably work, but the `user`will be force to learn how to work with the interface, and the application functionalities will consume a lot of time to develop - it will be easier to use tool that is already created and the user is familiar with (for example excel).

I know I can export/import data between T-SQL table and excel file, but is there a way to build some kind of collaboration between them - for example the excel to call a stored procedure which is returning the data (it will be nice if I can send a hash of the data or the rows in order to return only the rows that have been changed). And to call a stored procedure which can upload/delete/insert data in the table.

If not, I guess I am going to work with files - download the file, edit the data in excel, then upload it, if there aren't other ways?

Comment: 3 million rows is not considered "huge" these dasys

Comment: You are right. I said 2-3 millions because excel displays only up to 1 million - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do this in access. Setup an ODBC Connection on the users computer then add in a linked-table into the access db.

I don't think it would take too long for someone to create an application with a nice winform interface. We have one at my office where if you create a function/stored procedure in SQL starting with certain characters, lets say dbo.app_*******, it will appear as a report in the application and any parameters in the stored procedure will prompt the user to input a value in the app.